# Facebook login integration, programatically add UILabel not working

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

```
#import "whoViewController.h"

@interface whoViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePictureView;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;

@end
```

The above should be adding the labels to the view.

```
@implementation whoViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_likes"];
loginView.center = self.view.center;
loginView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:loginView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// This method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                        user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
self.profilePictureView.profileID = user.id;
self.nameLabel.text = user.name;
}

// Implement the loginViewShowingLoggedInUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a 
  logged-in user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
self.statusLabel.text = @"You're logged in as";
}

// Implement the loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser: delegate method to modify your app's UI for a
logged-out user experience
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
self.profilePictureView.profileID = nil;
self.nameLabel.text = @"";
self.statusLabel.text= @"You're not logged in!";
}
@end
```

I've implemented the above, as it says to in the Facebook tutorial, but for some reason the labels don't appear, any help on why this might be?
The actual logging in and out works, but the labels and changes to the text in the labels, doesn't work.

From previous experience, it should work, as the logic seems good.

Comment: Did you add those labels in an XIB/Storyboard? Are they connected? Are the delegate methods being invoked? Have you subscribed to the delegate protocol?

Comment: You probably forgot to drag those labels into your viewcontroller from the .storyboard/.xib file and connect them to the IBOutlets

Comment: The tutorial on facebook's iOS dev site, it says that those labels should work programatically & that there's no need to connect them to the storyboard. As the same happens with the login view which gets added but isn't visible on the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Facebook SDK you need to follow these 5 steps below, if you have any doubt take a look on FbLoginIntegrationSample on Github and review the Getting Started section on facebook Developers (references below):

1- Download and install Facebook SDK

2- Obtain a Facebook App ID (Login on facebook and create a new app on the App Dashboard)

3- Configure your Xcode project

- Import FacebookSDK.framework to the project
- Configure the .plist file (add FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName)

5- Start coding!

- Import FacebookSDK.framework to the project
- Reference FBLoginViewDelegate to the Main View Class (probably whoViewController.h)
- Link nameLabel, statusLabel and profilePictureView to the correspondents labels (profilePictureView must be linked to a UIView object)
- Configure the .plist file (add FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName)

One more hint:

1- Remember to set the loginView frame dimensions and position:

loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 5);

References:

**Sample Project**

https://github.com/carantes/FbLoginIntegrationSample

**Configuring:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial

Comment: I've followed the tutorial word for word, I'm just stuck on the final part where it shows the profile picture etc.. of the person logged in.

Comment: Please review the tutorial and be sure you reference the delegate on view controller --> LoginUIViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate> and the [FBLoginView class] on AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function

Comment: Can you provide any debug info, maybe you can add some output strings (NSLog) on loginViewFetchedUserInfo just to be sure the function is called

Comment: Hi, yes, I've got both of those, How do I do the second part? the log gin part? Thank you for trying

Comment: If you wanna put debug infos just type NSLog(@"Passed here");